# How to check if associated model has entries in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `RegularOpeningHour(dayOfWeek: integer)` that is associated to a model `OpeningTime(opens: time, closes: time)`. `RegularOpeningHour` has an 1:n relation to `OpeningTime`, so that a specific day can have many opening times.

*(I know that I simply could have one entry with 'opens' and 'closes' included in RegularOpeningHour but for other reasons I need this splitting)*

Now I want a `open?`-Method, that returns whether the business is opened or not. I tried the following in my model file *regular_opening_hour.rb*:

```
def open?
    RegularOpeningHour.where(dayOfWeek: Time.zone.now.wday).any? { |opening_hour| opening_hour.opening_times.where('? BETWEEN opens AND closes', Time.zone.now).any? }
end
```

Unforutnately, that doesn't work. Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create some scopes to make selecting open `OpeningTime`s and open `RegularOpeningHour`s less clunky. This makes creating the given selection much easier.

```
class OpeningTime < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  belongs_to :regular_opening_hour

  def self.open
    time = Time.current
    where(arel_table[:opens].lteq(time).and(arel_table[:closes].gteq(time)))
  end

  # ...

end
```

```
class RegularOpeningHour < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  has_many :opening_times

  def self.open
    where(
      dayOfWeek: Time.current.wday,
      id: OpeningTime.select(:regular_opening_hour_id).open,
    )
  end

  # ...

end
```

```
def open?
  RegularOpeningHour.open.any?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
def open?
  joins(:opening_times)
    .where(dayOfWeek: Time.current.wday)
    .where("opens <= :time AND closes >= :time", time: Time.current)
    .any?
end
```

EDIT: Missing ':' in the join

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to generate the correct SQL-Query:

 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "regular_opening_hours" INNER JOIN "opening_times" ON "opening_times"."regular_opening_hour_id" = "regular_opening_hours"."id" WHERE "regular_opening_hours"."dayOfWeek" = ? AND (opens <= '2018-08-07 07:28:54.202469' AND closes >
= '2018-08-07 07:28:54.202469')

But I get false, except the last entry has dayOfweek: 2 and opens: 2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC and closes: 2000-01-01 20:00:00 UTC

Comment: ok, I see it myself. The year is wrong. How can I just compare the time?

Comment: @MichaelL. You can using TIME function of mysql. https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time-function.php

Comment: Yeah! That works. I only have problems with UTC and local time

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix that UTC problem? Me (living +2 UTC) have always the the check with an diffrenz of 2 hours
E.g. Assuming opening hours are from 10:00 to 11:00 and now it is 10:30 locally, then the check says RegularOpeningHour.open? => false.
But when I change the opening hours to 08:00 to 09:00 and it's still 10:30 locally, the check says RegularOpeningHour.open? => true.
Therefore I guess it has something to do with time zones

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `has_many` association of `RegularOpeningHour` to `OpeningTime` you can use join query like below.:

```
RegularOpeningHour.joins(:opening_times).where(dayOfWeek: Time.zone.now.wday).where('? BETWEEN opening_times.opens AND opening_times.closes', Time.zone.now).any?
```